# iOS: Warning: Attempt to present <ModalViewController> on <ViewController>while a presentation is in progress

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to create a modal view controller after picking an image from the image picker. I use the code :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

   NSLog(@"Picker has returned");
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



   // TODO: make this all threaded?
   // crop the image to the bounds provided
   img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   NSLog(@"orig image size: %@", [[NSValue valueWithCGSize:img.size] description]);

   // save the image, only if it's a newly taken image:
   if([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera){
      UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
   }

   // self.image_View.image=img;
   //self.image_View.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;


   ModalViewController *sampleView = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
```

However, I receive the warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ModalViewController: 0x7561600> on <ViewController: 0x75a72e0> while a presentation is in progress!
```

and the modal view does not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **COMPLETE SOLUTION HERE**, John's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453001/meaning-of-warning-while-a-presentation-is-in-progress

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     // TODO: make this all threaded?
     // crop the image to the bounds provided
     img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     NSLog(@"orig image size: %@", [[NSValue valueWithCGSize:img.size] description]);

     // save the image, only if it's a newly taken image:
     if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
     }

     // self.image_View.image = img;
     // self.image_View.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    NSLog(@"Picker has returned");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:^{
                                ModalViewController *sampleView = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
                                [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
                             }];
}
```

Comment: Just to add that while the completion block executes after the view controller is dismissed, it is not immediately after. viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear get a chance to run before your completion block.

Comment: One short note, because i was once asked by a staff agent at Runtastic and i didn't know that:

Answer (score 5):

Here the issue is happening because, you are first dismissing the `UIImagePicker` and immediately you are displaying another view as modal view. That's why you are getting this error.

Check with the following code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

     img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     NSLog(@"orig image size: %@", [[NSValue valueWithCGSize:img.size] description]);

     if([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
     {
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
     }

     ModalViewController *sampleView = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
  }];
}
```

Comment: He still can dismiss it with animation

Comment: Your answer is just like mine (I'm gonna delete mine as it's irrelevant to have the same answer posted twice) . The solution is the method with the completion handler. But if he had used [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO] he wouldn't receive that warning at all.

Comment: @Moxy: don't delete your answer dude. There is lot of difference between both answers. Your's is best. So don't delete it.

Comment: I don't want it to seem that I stole the answer from you. I was editing it before you posted yours. Anyway my point is the solution is the same as @alandalusi should be using -dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: to dismiss the modal view controller also because -dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: has been deprecated since iOS 6.

Comment: @Moxy: don't feel like so. Our aim is to help him to find a solution. Sometimes two people's answer will be same. Because that is the solution. We need to solve his issue, whose answer is accepted that won't matter.