# While mail sending process using ios 8 simulators generates error

Tags: ios, swift, email, ios8, ios-simulator

When i am using simulator of iphone 5s such error is appears during mail sending and perfectly runs in ios 7 simulators.
It even does not show send option and only cancel option appears when it open ups mail sending page. What should i do to solve it please help me out. 
Thank you in advance

**ERROR:-**

> '_serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=4097  "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"
>   (connection to service named
>   com.apple.uikit.viewservice.com.apple.MailCompositionService)
>   {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.uikit.viewservice.com.apple.MailCompositionService}'
>
> viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: 'Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" 
>   {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}'

Comment: Show us your relevant code.

Comment: and the pop-up by Xcode:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/LcdY2.png

Answer (score 30, accepted):

FYI have the same problem with the iOS 8 simulator, having not seen the issue on iOS 6/7 simulators or iOS 7 hardware. Found this useful link:

[I have REAL misunderstanding with MFMailComposeViewController in Swift (iOS8) in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in) (note that Swift is not part of the problem)

On the 19th I'll have proper iOS 8 hardware to test on so might be able to confirm if it only happens on the simulator!

EDIT: I can confirm that I'm not seeing it on my iPhone 6 Plus device having seen it every single time I launched it in the iPhone 6 Plus simulator.

Comment: Ditto - iOS 8.2 crashes with simulator as above, but code runs fine on iPad 2.

Comment: I see it on my iPhone 6 iOS 8.4.1 and on my Xcode simulators

Comment: Confirmed on iOS Simulator 8.1 crashes the app while on actual iPhone 5s 8.4 works fine.

Comment: As of XCode 7.2/iOS 9.2 simulator, this is still happening. Per https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4415 it looks like a known bug. Of course the [opacity of Apple's bug reporting system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports) means we have no idea if it's gotten any love or not. Hard to believe this is still an issue!

Answer (score 10):

Issue is with IOS 8 Simulater . When checked with all devices in IOS 7 and 7.1 Simulater ,MFMailComposeViewController works fine .