# MFMailComposerViewController via UIActivityViewController error

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to open a mail composer via UIActivityViewController on iOS8. (So, there's no my own code for this procedure) The result on device is continues error logging (the messages continue to be logged even after I close mail and quit to different UI controller)

**AX Exchange error: Error Domain=Accessibility Code=0 "Remote service does not respond to _accessibilityMachPort" UserInfo=0x14fd1b60 {NSLocalizedDescription=Remote service does not respond to _accessibilityMachPort}**

On a simulator the MFMailComposeViewController just dismisses right after I present it with error:

**viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7b6eb4b0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}**

P.S.  I have xcode 6 and testing on iOS 8.0.2 iPhone 5s. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Have you been able to explain or resolve this?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: I see. I'm seeing these messages as well: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515414/kif-output-ax-exchange-error-error-domain-accessibility-code-0-remote-service)

Comment: let me know if you fix this plz

Comment: I've found out a bit more (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28592706/1789384)).

Comment: Same problem, so far I've only tested on the simulator - with the exact same failure and message.  (My test case is pretty minimal, not sure how we could be causing this problem.)  Anyone try to file a bug with Apple?

Comment: Same exact thing happens using MPMediaPickerController.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem in my product and after doing some debugging, I narrowed down that it's the combination of presented ViewController and custom keyboard. That means my application was showing this error message only when I navigated to any presented ViewController (like mail composer) and a custom keyboard was activated.

During further hit-and-try, **I was able to get rid of this error message by removing MonkeyTalk library**, which was being used for automated testing.

I am not sure if same scenario applies to you, but I am sure that some library is conflicting with some keyboard and that's resulting in error message.

P.S. in my case my application was being freezed by those error messages.

Comment: I got same problem as Stas and exact same message, without using a custom keyboard and without the MonkeyTalk Library.

Comment: @jbbenni I am not sure if this applies to your case or not, but there must be some 3rd party library, that is conflicting with keyboard. Try removing any 3rd party library and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: The only libraries I link are: CoreText, MessageUI, UIKit, Foundation, and CoreGraphics.  I'd be surprised if those were incompatible or conflicted with Apple mail controller.  Not sure why you think it's a keyboard conflict.  My symptoms are identical to Stas (above).

Comment: Correction:  I get EXACTLY the same symptom on the simulator, but the mail function appears to work properly on an actual iPad device.  Perhaps there are two problems: 1) Apple broke email on the simulator, and 2) some other issue is muddying the water.   See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25801366/1035697