# KIF output: AX Exchange error: Error Domain=Accessibility Code=0 "Remote service does not respond to _accessibilityMachPort"

Tags: ios, ios8, integration-testing, ios8.1, kif

When running KIF integration tests on device with iOS 8.1.3 I get lots of diagnostic messages of the following kind as console output:

> AX Exchange error: Error Domain=Accessibility Code=0 "Remote service
>   does not respond to _accessibilityMachPort" UserInfo=0x1a55de50
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Remote service does not respond to
>   _accessibilityMachPort}

This occurs during a call to `waitForAccessibilityElement:view:withElementMatchingPredicate:tappable:`.

Otherwise testing works as expected, it just seems a bit verbose. So I am wondering: is this kind of diagnostic output a feature or a bug? How can it be explained? What can or should I do about it, if anything?

Comment: Restarting the simulator did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These warnings apparently disappear if one enables `VoiceOver` on the device (with iOS 8.1 `Settings` | `General` | `Accessibility`), however now one gets spammed with (perhaps) lots of redundant audio instead of log messages.

KIF is employing iOS Accessibility (VoiceOver) for what is not its normal purpose, but for locating UI elements by their `accessibilityIdentifier`s and `accessibilityLabel`s (without serving Accessibility). It is conceivable that the same pattern applies in [reported cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336227/mfmailcomposerviewcontroller-via-uiactivityviewcontroller-error) around `MFMailComposerViewController` for filling mail messages in the UI. If that is so, it may be fair enough if iOS 8.1 reduces Accessibility (VoiceOver) services when they are not needed (enabled) for their normal purposes. That could explain why a Mach port is (apparently) not bound and could in turn explain the observed warning messages.

Comment: Having the same issue with iOS 10 on iPhone 6s using SafariViewController (I don't open it, but facebook SDK does).

Answer (score 16):

For people working with Xamarin.iOS, disabling `Xamarin.Calabash.Start(); // For Test Cloud` suspends the non-stop logging

Comment: Could you describe "why" this works? Seeing similar suggestions around the web: https://chrisrisner.com/Xamarin-iOS-Error-Confusion