# UIDocumentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem stopped working well on iOS8.1

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8

My app has a document interaction controller which is used to open documents in other apps. 
The following code displays a button that opens the 'Open in' menu and allows the user to open the file in other apps – i.e. Send it by mail if the user chose the mail app in the 'Open in' menu, the mail app creates a new email and automatically attaches the file to the mail body.

The following code worked fine in iOS7 but stopped working well on iOS8+. Files are not being attached to mails and I get an error log message.

**Declaration for UIDocumentInteractionController:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController* interactionController;
```

**Initialization:**

```
self.interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:self.url];
self.interactionController.delegate = self;
self.interactionController.name = self.file.name;
```

**The call for the 'Open in' menu:**

```
[self.interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.openInBarButtonItem animated:YES];
```

**Example for error message received after opening an excel file:**

> Unknown activity items supplied: (
>           {
>           "com.microsoft.excel.xls" = <504b0304 ....000000>;
>       },
>       "" )
>
> viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"
>   UserInfo=0x… {Message=Service Connection Interrupted} (lldb).

I would appreciate any ideas to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Ori

Comment: using a simulator? may be a similar issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801366/while-mail-sending-process-using-ios-8-simulators-generates-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Code

```
        BOOL IOS8=SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0");
        if (IOS8){
        if ([interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES]) {
            NSLog(@"menu is presented");
        }
```