# iOS app crashing when trying to create email

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting the following dialog pop up whenever I try and create an email from within my app:

[image: crash]

I have tried deploying to 7, 7.1 & 8 and it crashed on each version.

Here is the error log:

```
2015-06-20 12:53:09.434 CDM App[1045:29809] Result: canceled
2015-06-20 12:53:09.446 CDM App[1045:29780] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7ae62340 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

any help greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks,

Comment: did u try on iPhone device. can u post the code u have been trying

Answer (score 0):

Possibly duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801366/while-mail-sending-process-using-ios-8-simulators-generates-error).

There is issue with composing mail on simulators, it will not effect on real device

You should also visit [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=20726).

Comment: Hi @Mrugesh , I don't think this is the same issue I am having, I read that question before posting and it refers to ios 8, saying they have it working in ios 7, whereas my project doesn't work when I emulate on any version of ios?