# Email composure iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6gm

I'm trying to open email composure in iOS 8 from Xcode 6, but getting an error. The same code is working fine if I'm trying from Xcode 5. Later I downloaded a sample code from apple developer portal:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html

But the result is same. Is there something, or some setting, I'm missing to optimise the code for Xcode 6

Here is the code:
in my button action

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Hello from California!"];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

// Attach an image to the email
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"rainy"];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

email delegate

```
self.feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
// Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending canceled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail saved";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sent";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending failed";
        break;
    default:
        self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail not sent";
        break;
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

result:

> email composure delegate disappearing automatically with result 0,
>   i.e., MFMailComposeResultCancelled
>
> with error codes : MessageComposer[10993:196902]
>   viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7b93f7e0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

and

> 2014-09-17 22:04:22.538 MessageComposer[10993:205761]
>    timed out waiting for
>   fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService

Comment: What's the error? Show the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Again, what is the error? Which line?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in

Comment: @hoiberg42 you are correct, that are the error codes I am getting after the email composure controller dismissing itself.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, tried the globalMailer approach but it still does it. 
Mail view controller appears, gets stuck, and dismisses automatically. :/

Comment: I just tested on a iOS 8 device and it seems that the globalMailer works. So it must be a Simulator issue...

Comment: @Vrasidas: yes this is true, its just the simulator issue, If you post the answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

By the looks of it, this is a simulator-only issue. (iOS 8 simulator)
The globalMailer approach works ok on devices.

If anyone encounters this problem, just test on a real device.

Comment: I had the issue in simulator only as well.  Tested on the device through test flight and it was fine.

Comment: if you do your test on a Simulator running iOS7.1 your code will work fine as well

Comment: I have the same problem too on iOs simulator, but on real device is working fine :)

Comment: how can this still be going on?  I get the same error for 9.1 and 9.0 on the simulator.