# MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app

First, my app worked fine on iOS 7, since iOS 8 i can't send in-app email thru "MFMailComposeViewController". 
Message window comes up, only shows subject of the mail and closes within seconds.
I found this thread here which describes my problem and now tried to implement the answer from "Joe Blow" https://stackoverflow.com/a/25864182/4061869

But im getting some errors, some sematic and parse issues.

Worst thing according to this part of the workaround:

```
Of course have this in your Prefix file

#define APP ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
// it's worth noting that is the delegate, not the "application"
```

Leads to this error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'

Anyone knows where the problem can be?
I tried different wordings on 'AppDelegate' according to my filename of the appdelegat.h/.m but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the app delegate in whichever ViewController you are working in, by using:

```
AppNameAppDelegate *APP = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

To state the obvious, by AppName I mean the name of your application. Make sure to import the AppDelegate.h into your .m file too.

```
#import "AppNameAppDelegate.h"
```

For the record, I am also having the same issue with `MFMailComposeViewController`,and I have tried the method suggested in the post you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in/25864182#25864182) (creating a global mail composer), but it still won't work for me using the iOS 8 simulator. Apparently it works on a physical device running iOS 8, but I personally cannot confirm that just yet.

Comment: I added the import line to the prefix file and most errors are gone. Now i got a new one with this line `[APP cycleTheGlobalMailComposer];`
which says `No visible @interface for 'ITLAppDelegate' declares the selector 'cycleTheGlobalMailComposer'`

Do you get any errors while compiling when using the suggested method?

Comment: If you have your `cycleTheGlobalMailComposer` method in the `AppDelegate.m` file, then you need to call that method from whichever view that you want to bring up the mail composer. You can do this by defining it in the `AppDelegate.h` file by: `- (void)cycleTheGlobalMailComposer;`. Then call this method like: `ITLAppDelegate *callMethod = [[ITLAppDelegate alloc]init];
[callMethod cycleTheGlobalMailComposer];`. This should get rid of any errors. You should set breakpoints when that method gets called so you can see exactly where it's going. This should stop the compile errors.

Comment: The `- (void)cycleTheGlobalMailComposer;` is defined in the ITLAppDelegate.m as its written in the tutorial. Now i tried your code `ITLAppDelegate *callMethod = [[ITLAppDelegate alloc]init]; [callMethod cycleTheGlobalMailComposer];` but the error is still `No visible @interface for 'ITLAppDelegate' declares the selector 'cycleTheGlobalMailComposer'`.

Comment: Hmm, have you declared the `globalMailComposer` in your `ViewController.h` that is using it? `@property (nonatomic, strong) MFMailComposeViewController *globalMailComposer;` - you should do this in both the `AppDelegate.h` and also the `ViewController.h` which is calling the `cycleTheGlobalMailComposer` method, and `@synthesize` it if necessary.

Comment: Hm, no change. But i think i have a solution now. I moved `- (void)cycleTheGlobalMailComposer;`to my ViewController.h and call it with `[self cycleTheGlobalMailComposer];`. Now i can compile without errors an within my app the email window opens with correct data.
I try tomorrow if this works on a device too and email sent correctly!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's cool man, good job getting it working! So does it work properly in the iOS 8 simulator? With the correct recipient/subject/body etc without throwing any errors? I couldn't get it to work, maybe I'll give it another go if it worked for you :)