# _UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm having a problem with `MFMailComposeViewController`

I'm getting this error

```
viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=... {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

with this code

```
- (IBAction) mailbutton:(id)sender 
{

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
    {

        [MSAPP.globalMailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentViewController:MSAPP.globalMailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

    } 
    else 
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Unable to mail. No email on this device?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [MSAPP cycleTheGlobalMailComposer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with the iOS 8 simulator. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25864182/3107564) for a possible workaround.

> You MUST allocate and initiate MFMailComposeViewController in an
>   earlier stage, and hold it in one static variable, whenever it's
>   needed, get the static MFMailComposeViewController instance and
>   present it.
>
> AND you will almost certainly have to "cycle" the global
>   MFMailComposeViewController after each use. It is not reliable to
>   "re-use" the same one. Have a global routine which release and then
>   re-initializes the singleton MFMailComposeViewController. Call it each
>   time after you are finished with it

Credit goes to ["Joe Blow"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/joe-blow) for the post. Judging by your code, you have already declared  global mail composer. Try "recycling" it as the post suggests to see if that solves your problem. I am having the same issue and unfortunately this solution doesn't fix mine. I can confirm this solution works on the iOS 7.1 simulator but not iOS 8, although it has been suggested it will work on a physical iOS 8 device.