# MFMailComposeViewController dismisses itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

**NOTE:** I have tried every possible solution I have found on SO, and none of them seem to resolve my issue. Hence I have posted a new question.

**Scenario:**

I have the following view hierarchy, and I am attempting to present `MFMailComposeViewController` from the "Request an Invite" view.

[image]

As you can see, I'm presenting the mail compose controller from a presented controller, but I doubt this is the issues, since I have tried presenting it on the root view controller itself also(from it's own code, of course).

The code I have used to present the mail composer is as follows:

```
- (IBAction) requestButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    MFMailComposeViewController* composeController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composeController setSubject:@"Too many happy memories sucked out. Now I'm just miserable."];
    [composeController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"customerCare@azkaban.org"]];
    [composeController setMailComposeDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:composeController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Problem:**

After I **present** the `MFMailComposeViewController`, it dismisses itself after a delay of 2 or 3 seconds with the following log:

> ... viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7fd4b0cc86e0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
>
> ... < MFMailComposeRemoteViewController: 0x7fd4b0d9b660 > timed out waiting
>   for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService

And the delegate method `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` is called with result `MFMailComposeResultCancelled`.

I have tried all possible solutions I have come across SO, including removing `UINavigationBar` **appearance** code, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just test on a real device..  seems to be a Simulator issue

Comment: Same thing. Happens on device also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in

Comment: Am experiencing this problem in iOS 11. Composer only seems to dismiss itself on older devices (5, 5s, and 6). 7/8/X all work fine.