# MfMailComposerViewController crash on ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm getting a serious problem on `MFMailComposerViewController` when its entering to the viewcontroller.My project is on cocos2d ios.

```
[[CCDirector SharedDirector] presentViewController:MC Animated:YES completation:nil];//crashing here
```

stack trace:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target >>.'

Comment: please provide exception, and stacktrace

Comment: Totally explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25864182/294884

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <CCDirectorDisplayLink = 0x15876e00 | Size: 568 x 320, view = <CCGLView: 0x14d9bb10; frame = (0 0; 568 320); layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0x14da47a0>>>.'

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create the mail view controller?

Comment: Are you using the canSendMail method of the MFMailComposeViewController to check if you can send mails?

Comment: Ya I think you solved my problem.crash happening on the device and I use cansendmail method and symptom is there was no mail a/c that's why its crashing ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before to alloc and present the MFMailComposeViewController check if the device can send mails:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
//your code here

}
```