# How to create send email for ios 8?

Tags: objective-c, email, ios8, send

First, i create send email for ios 7 but when running for ios 8 cannot type destination email address and others, after that pop up email close ..
is there special process to send email for ios 8 ?

```
// Open Email and add attachment
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *recipients = @[@""];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailController setToRecipients:recipients];
[mailController setSubject:@"File"];
NSData *attachment = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:xlsPath];
[mailController addAttachmentData:attachment   mimeType:@"application/vnd.ms-excel" fileName:@"Export.xls"];

mailController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you testing on a device or the simulator?

Comment: device,
if i test devise using ios 8 error, cannot type destination email address and others..

Comment: I would have a look at the answer to this question for the proper way to use an MFMailComposeViewController - [I have REAL misunderstanding with MFMailComposeViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in) - ignore the fact the question mentions Swift.