# ios 8 custom keyboard UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm pulling my hair for this error that i got when i tried to make a custom keyboard ,

```
MobileSafari[1234:36764] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: 
Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain
error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7f971da0f6a0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

Can anyone knows what does this error means?!

Comment: Hey some code would probably be helpful, nevertheless here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in somebody seems to have a similar problem.

Comment: This is valid when you're testing Mail function and i know it's not available on the simulator ,but how could i test my custom keyboard not on a simulator !!

Comment: Did you resolved this issue? Am also facing this issue

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Simulator, it could entirely be the Simulator's fault.

Check out: [I have REAL misunderstanding with MFMailComposeViewController in Swift (iOS8) in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in/25864182#25864182)

For a workaround.

Comment: i got it ,but how should i test my custom keyboard ?!

Comment: I'm facing this error even if I use a real device for debugging

Comment: @Meseery Remember to mark this as the correct answer if it worked.