# Unable to send mail using MFMailComposeViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, email

I got an error :

**viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7c3f4600 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}**

```
 if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Contact"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"Here is some main text in the email!" isHTML:NO];
        [mail setToRecipients:@[self.salonemail.text]];

        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else{
        [self showAlert:@"Looks like your device can't send emails"];
        }

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have REAL misunderstanding with MFMailComposeViewController in Swift (iOS8) in Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested on real devices? This usually comes in iPhone simulators.