# Showing UIAlertController first then MFMailComposeViewController. Works only first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have `UIAlertController`. On click of OK, presenting `MFMailComposeViewController`. I dismiss the `MFMailComposeViewController` by tapping on cancel button in email compose screen. `MFMailComposeViewController`'s delegate methods are called properly while dismissing. `MFMailComposeViewController` dismisses successfully. Immediately after that if I try the same feature(flow) again. I am not getting alert, rather getting below error. What could be the reason? I tried most of the solution available in stackoverflow. still getting the same issue.

> Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x13890beb0> on <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x1371ef000> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

I am using `self presentViewController` to present alertcontroller and `MFMailComposeViewController`.

sample code is here :

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(nullable NSError *)error{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];


}


UIAlertController * alertController=   [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message"                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                             MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposerVC = [MFMailComposeViewController new];

                             mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

                             if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {


                                 [self presentViewController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailComposerVC animated: true completion: nil];
                             }

                         }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                             }];

    [alertController addAction:ok];
    [alertController addAction:cancel];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:false completion:nil];
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Can you please post some code? and decide whether you are using Swift or Objective-C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25864182/988769

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code to present mail controller :

```
UIAlertController * alertController=   [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message"                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction  actionWithTitle:@"Ok"  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                         [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

                         mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

                         if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

                            [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:mailComposerVC
                                                                                             animated:YES
                                                                                           completion:nil];

                         }

                     }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)  {
                             [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];

[alertController addAction:ok];
[alertController addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:false completion:nil];
```

Comment: The above lines of code is part of button action. My requirement is, to show alert before showing email composer.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's exactly causing a problem. I've found a few possible reasons, hopefully, fixing one of them will end up as a solution to your problem.

You should call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` on the presenting view controller not the presented one. Even though it usually works, in your case it could brake something. You have 3 places where you do it wrong. This is one of them:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(nullable NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  // `controller` is replaces with `self`
}
```

Also you shouldn't present `mailComposerVC` before `alertController` is dismissed. You may use the completion block for this.

Do you test on the simulator? `MFMailComposeViewController` doesn't work properly there. Try to run on a real device, maybe, the crash will magically disappear.