# Swift: Dismiss viewController 1 then present viewController 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I want to dismiss a loader view controller then present an `UIDocumentInteractionController`. I found an objective-c solution, but I want the Swift 3 one.

This is the objective-c code taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453001/meaning-of-warning-while-a-presentation-is-in-progress/17120065#17120065):

```
// Does not break
[viewController1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self presentViewController:viewController2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
}];
```

I translated like this in Swift 3:

```
 self.dismiss(animated: false, completion:{
                                self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: destinationUrl!)
                                self.docController!.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)

})
```

It works fine, but I want to be sure that the `completion:^{` in objective-c means  `completion:{` in Swift 3.

Comment: yes, they are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Though you don't need to write completion explicitly in Swift 3.

You can write something like this too.

```
self.dismiss(animated: false) { 
    self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: destinationUrl!)
    self.docController!.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
}
```